# Reordering Buddy Press profile navigation

Tags: php, buddypress, navigation, profiles, conditional-content

I am using this code to reorder the positions of the menu items for BuddyPress profile. I am using the xprofile (not sure if that makes a difference). Here is the code that I am trying to use:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin name: BP custom
Plugin URI: http://pittbullweb.com
Description: Customs for Buddy Press
Version: 0.1
Author URI: http://pittbullweb.com
*/

function bbg_change_profile_tab_order() {
global $bp;

    $bp->bp_nav['profile']['position'] = 10;
    $bp->bp_nav['activity']['position'] = 20;
    $bp->bp_nav['blogs']['position'] = 30;
    $bp->bp_nav['friends']['position'] = 40;
    $bp->bp_nav['messages']['position'] = 50;
    $bp->bp_nav['groups']['position'] = 60;
    $bp->bp_nav['settings']['position'] = 70;
}
add_action('bp_setup_nav', 'bbg_change_profile_tab_order', 999 );
?>
```

I am going by the instructions given [here](http://themekraft.com/customize-profile-and-group-menus-in-buddypress/) to be able to do this. However when I go to activate the plugin i get a fatal error:

**Fatal error:** Cannot redeclare bbg_change_profile_tab_order() (previously declared in /var/www/vhosts/giftcardswapping.com/demo/wp-content/plugins/bp-custom.php:11) **in /var/www/vhosts/giftcardswapping.com/demo/wp-content/plugins/bp-custom.php on line 20**

I have also tried renaming the function as well and still receive the same fatal error.

I do not understand how it is redeclared anywhere. I would appreciate any help to figure this out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the function both in bp-custom.php and in your plugin.

You don't need a plugin.

Put your code in plugins/bp-custom.php only.

Or in your-theme/functions.php

Comment: You have to create the bp-custom.php as a plugin as it is not something that comes with BuddyPress. So it shouldn't be creating a conflict. The code was only placed in that file and nowhere else.

Comment: >You have to create the bp-custom.php as a plugin == FALSE. bp-custom is a FILE, not a plug-in.  That is the source of your problem. Read the docs: http://codex.buddypress.org/extending-buddypress/bp-custom-php/

Comment: If its not a plugin why does it operate from the wp-content/plugins folder? I guess that is where I am confused. And do you have to activate it as a plugin via Wordpress admin? Or does it just run automatically?

Comment: It's not a plugin, so you don't have to activate it. Please read the documentation link I provided. Or just try what I suggested in my initial response. Or not...

Comment: I did read it i was just confusing myself. I do that quite often sometimes. Thank you for all your help. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach would be to rename your function, this way you won't be re-declaring an already existing function.

Try changing bbg_change_profile_tab_order to my_bbg_change_profile_tab_order

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion however I have already tried this and still get the same fatal error.